# Create Google compliant dynamic XML sitemap

Tags: asp.net, xml, sitemap

I want to create a dynamic (fetching data from the database) XML sitemap which I can submit to Google webmaster tools.

Surprisingly, I couldn't find any recent controls/code online to do this. The most recent code I found was this http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/12/02/432188.aspx which is for ASP.Net 2.0. I don't mind using this, but I suspect it's outdated.

Can somebody please point me in the direction of code which accomplishes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options include:

The ASP.Net [SiteMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178434(v=VS.80).aspx) infrastructure. It allows you to write a custom sitemap provider like this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178434(v=VS.80).aspx), which uses Micosoft Access, to generate a sitemap.

You can also find a very simple sitemap generator project on this [site](http://dario-g.com/projects.aspx).

Another option (and fun learning experience) is to write your own by just looking at the sitemap [protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php), and using Linq To SQL along with Linq To Xml to generate the format. Here is an [example](http://jacquesbron.com/blog/database/linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-xml-in-action-from-database-to-xml/) uses Linq To SQL and Linq To XML to generate XML.

Finally, Google also accepts [RSS/Atom](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) feeds, so you could generate one of those instead. If you go this route then you can make use of the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class. There are also a couple open source [options](http://www.rssdotnet.com/) available.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i just done it recently using LinqToXMl

[How to generate xsi:schemalocation attribute correctly when generating a dynamic sitemap.xml with LINQ to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346460/linq-to-xml-dynamic-sitemap-xml)

Actually the string that is returned by that code is written directly to the Response object. I use a .ashx HttpHandler to deliver the content as XML and using Routing to serve it under the name of sitemap.xml. Also you should put it on your robots.txt file